Ansible how to convert boolean types true and false to corresponding strings
Here is my playbook, I didn't use the boolean type directly for compatibility with the previous version which was fetched from Inventory, I looked at the playbook and it was when: cluster_allinone == "true", which I might have forgotten to change when executing the script, so I wanted to override the value of cluster_allinone without modifying the previous playbook.
- name: check node counnt
  hosts: all:!gaop-vip-addresses
  tasks:
    - name: Get the number of nodes in group2
      set_fact:
        worker_count: "{{ groups['k8s-worker'] | length }}"

    - debug:
        var: worker_count

    - name: set cluster_allinone var
      set_fact:
        cluster_allinone: 'true'
      when: (worker_count | int) == 0

    - name: set cluster_allinone var
      set_fact:
        cluster_allinone: 'false'
      when: (worker_count | int) > 0

    - debug:
        var: cluster_allinone

    - debug:
        msg: single
      when: cluster_allinone == "true"

    - debug:
        msg: mutil
      when: cluster_allinone  == "false"

But cluster_allinone seems to be of boolean type, I've tried to_json and ternary('true', 'false').
    - name: set cluster_allinone var
      set_fact:
        temp: 'true'
      when: (worker_count | int) == 0

    - name: set cluster_allinone var
      set_fact:
        temp: 'false'
      when: (worker_count | int) > 0


--- try but fail


    - name: set cluster_allinone var
      set_fact:
        cluster_allinone: "{{temp | to_json}}"

    - name: set cluster_allinone var
      set_fact:
        cluster_allinone: "{{(worker_count | int) == 0}}"

    - name: set cluster_allinone var
      set_fact:
        cluster_allinone: "{{temp | ternary('true', 'false')}}"

ansible --version
ansible 2.4.5.0
  config file = /data/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /data/ansible/lib/ansible
  executable location = /data/ansible/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2018, 06:48:02) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Spent way too much time on this one, any help is appreciated!

There is absolute no need for the set_fact tasks and the requested type conversion, see Vladimirs answer. For more background information see as well Ansible: How to preserve a variable data type at set_fact? and The bool filter in Ansible doesn't output true for non-empty strings.

See Boolean variables. Indeed, the type of cluster_allinone is bool
    - set_fact:
        cluster_allinone: 'true'
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cluster_allinone | type_debug }}"

gives
  msg: bool

Use it as a boolean. This will simplify the code
    - debug:
        msg: single
      when: cluster_allinone

    - debug:
        msg: multi
      when: not cluster_allinone

gives
  msg: single



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        cluster_allinone: true

    - debug:
        msg: single
      when: cluster_allinone

    - debug:
        msg: multi
      when: not cluster_allinone



Thanks, I see what you mean, but one more question, I set cluster_allinone = false in the inventory file, and I debug it - debug:         msg: "{{ cluster_allinone | type_debug }}", ok: [192.168.1.52] => {     "msg": "unicode" }，Do you know how to convert it to a bool type?

@HuaJFrame, via the bool filter.

If you plan to assign the variable INI style convert it explicitly to Boolean  when: cluster_allinone | bool. The problem is that INI style is always a string.

To ensure compatibility with your existing playbook and to properly handle the 'cluster_allinone' variable as a string ('"true" or "false"'), you can adjust your playbook by using 'set_fact' to explicitly set the 'cluster_allinone' variable as a string based on the worker_count.
You can fixed the following:

name: check node count
hosts: all:!gaop-vip-addresses
tasks:

name: Get the number of nodes in group2
set_fact:
worker_count: "{{ groups['k8s-worker'] | length }}"

debug:
var: worker_count

name: set cluster_allinone var to true if worker_count is 0
set_fact:
cluster_allinone: 'true'
when: (worker_count | int) == 0

name: set cluster_allinone var to false if worker_count is greater than 0
set_fact:
cluster_allinone: 'false'
when: (worker_count | int) > 0

debug:
var: cluster_allinone

debug:
msg: single
when: cluster_allinone == "true"

debug:
msg: multiple
when: cluster_allinone == "false"
Good Luck!!!





Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem, my first playbook paragraph seems to be the answer you gave. Also, your answer sounds like Ai, which is static in the community.

Please learn how to format your code appropriately.
